# VSCode compilerPath issue with STM32

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, stm32

So, VSCode was working happily for writing code for my STM microcontroller (STM32WB). I would write the code in VSCode and compile and run in STM32CubeIDE.
Lately, however, VSCode's IntelliSense is acting up. It detects problems such as
`identifier "uint8_t" is undefined`. Furthermore, the 'Output' tab of VSCode gives the following error:

```
Unable to resolve configuration with compilerPath: "C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.8.0/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe"
```

The path itself appears to be fine. If I issue that command from command prompt, I get

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

which is the expected response.

Any suggestions on what I can try next? I feel like I'm missing something small!

More info:

- I've tried extensively playing around in the c_cpp_properties.json
  file.
- I've tried downloading another toolchain through STM32CubeIDE and using that path instead.
- I've tried adding the path to the Windows environment path.

Here is my c_cpp_properties.json file (most of the settings are copy/paste from what STM32CubeIDE sets up by default:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "STM32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "C:\\ST\\STM32CubeIDE_1.8.0\\STM32CubeIDE\\plugins\\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127\\tools\\**",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Drivers/STM32WBxx_HAL_Driver/Inc",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32WBxx/Include",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Drivers/CMSIS/Include",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Core/Inc",
            "${workspaceFolder}/STM32CubeIDE/Application/Core",
            "${workspaceFolder}/STM32CubeIDE/Drivers/STM32WBxx_HAL_Driver",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN/interface/patterns/ble_thread",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN/ble/core",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN/utilities",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN/ble",
            "${workspaceFolder}/STM32_WPAN/App",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN/ble/core/template",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Utilities/sequencer"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE",
            "USE_HAL_DRIVER",
            "DEBUG",
            "STM32WB55xx"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.8.0/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe",
        "compilerArgs": [
            "-mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DUSE_STM32WBXX_NUCLEO -DCORE_CM4 -DSTM32WB55xx -c -I../../Core/Inc -I../../Utilities/lpm/tiny_lpm -I../../Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN/interface/patterns/ble_thread/shci -I../../Utilities/sequencer -I../../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32WBxx/Include -I../../Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN/interface/patterns/ble_thread -I../../Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN/interface/patterns/ble_thread/tl -I../../STM32_WPAN/App -I../../Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN/ble/core -I../../Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN -I../../Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN/ble/core/template -I../../Drivers/BSP/P-NUCLEO-WB55.Nucleo -I../../Drivers/STM32WBxx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../../Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN/ble/core/auto -I../../Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN/utilities -I../../Middlewares/ST/STM32_WPAN/ble -I../../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb"
        ],
        "cStandard": "gnu11",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++11",
        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-arm",
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

Comment: Probably the best approach is to start all over with the blink-leds example projects and port your project onto it. In order to prevent these issues in the future, creating a local git repo would certainly help! It's just a matter of running "git init" in the top project dir and then commiting everything.

Comment: Somewhere there probably needs to be a `-I` pointing at the STM32 gcc port's equivalent of gcc\include.

Comment: (Also, integrating your favourite ARM debugger in VS Code sounds painful, but I haven't used it so I wouldn't know.)

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? If you update the STM32CubeIDE, the compiler path could change. Also, if you added the path to the environment, try setting the `compilerPath` to just `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe`.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions - it helped me to take a step back and explore new options.

Answer (score 0):

The [c_cpp_properties.json reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) indicates that some fields are optional. Indeed, simply commenting out the optional `compilerArgs` parameter resolves the issue. At least to a point that IntelliSense is working correctly again. Note that some of the -DXXXX parameters had to be moved to `defines` (e.g. -DUSE_STM32WBXX_NUCLEO).

It does make some sense, since you are already defining a lot of the `compilerArgs` elsewhere in the .json file (like `defines` and `includePath`).